# Is it possible to make .so library from java code?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, decompiling

I write programs on Java for Android. I am trying to hide my java code from decompilation. Is it possible to make .so library from java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "hide my java code from decompilation" you should use [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

No obfuscation is perfect, but at least with proguard, the attacker can't get back to the same source code you started with.

And remember even with compiled c in a `.so` it can be reverse engineered, so it's not like that's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question:

> Is it possible to make .so library from java code?

No you can't, you have to use JNI and write C code that implements the native functions you define in your Java code. This way, the `.so` library is compiled from C code.

Comment: May be there is any third-part tools that makes possible to "convert" Java bytecode to native? Like RoboVM does for iOS https://robovm.com http://postimg.org/image/pjaxod17j

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with that tools, and don't know about them. My experience is with JNI and C (not C++). This is the only way I know to do what you want.